# Bootstrap select list with form-control class renders differently on Internet Explorer 8

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <select class="form-control input">..</select>
</div>
```

This HTML appears like this in IE8:

[image]

and like this in the modern browsers:

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this?